# Massive CPU utilisation and large thread count for wrapper-macosx-universal-32 child java process

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, java

I've got a java process with the parent process 'wrapper-macosx-universal-32' that is using most of my CPU on snow leopard with thread counts hitting the 300 mark.  It's the actual child process with the high thread count/CPU.

Any ideas?  Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: And how is that process called?

Comment: what's a good way of finding out.. I can sample the process using the Activity Monitor if that's any help.  Better ask first.. there's a lot junk printed out.

Comment: That would be an idea, at least until the call graph.

Comment: changed the question when I noticed the process 'wrapper-macosx-universal-32' was the parent of the java process.

Comment: @alemaster now which one is parent and which one is child? Titke and body seem to contradict each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably the freenet-node daemon (from the freenetproject.org), not a virus or other badware.

It is only bad when you are online using your mobile phone and your provider beeing bloodsuckers who charge your weight in gold as soon as your traffic exceeds 1GB a month

Comment: I solved this months ago but forgot to post an answer!  Yes, I remember it was Freenet.. I was playing around with it.

Answer (score 3):

i'm also looking for what exactly it is.
i found it when i was sniffing my network, noticing massive traffic from my machine to targets all over the world. it's sending and quite much also receiving from the targets.

conclusion so far, ***it's something BAD! KILL IT!*** with fire!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Activity Monitor and enable "All processes" from the drop-down-menu. If you don't do it, then you might not see the process. Then you can find out, what process is causing the cpu load. In my case this was an antivirus product for the mac. I deinstalled it.

Comment: Yes, this was already enabled.  It's the wrapper-macosx-universal-32 that is the parent process that's causing the utilisation.  I better update my question about this.